# How to upgrade to Yosemite without AppStore

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I just can't add my credit card into Apple Id, I've tried hard, really.

I've manage to find a way how to install xcode, new iTunes and so on, but still not last OS upgrade. I've found information about downloading ISO and performing a clean install, but I don't want to loose my settings and everything.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have AppleID account without Credit Card.

[image: no credit card]

It works just fine in getting latest updates like Yosemite.

Comment: Damn it. No, really. Solution was that easy, but some manuals clearly said that you **can't** upgrade without confirmed credit card. Thanks.